# Why does `git log --parents` return the initial commit when it is the only commit

Tags: git

My repo has only an initial commit:

```
$ git log
commit 6wny3w6k677lr4t4adauv4uctyl6ue38lcozsxbx
Author: Test <test@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri May 01:29:13 2023 +0100

    Initial commit
```

Since this is the initial commit, it has no parents. But when I try `git log --parents`, the commit itself is returned:

```
$ git log --parents
commit 6wny3w6k677lr4t4adauv4uctyl6ue38lcozsxbx
Author: Test <test@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri May 01:29:13 2023 +0100

    Initial commit
```

Why is this?

(Apologies if this is a dupe. If this question has already been answered elsewhere, please let me know and I will delete this post.)

**EDIT:** Sorry, I mistook `git log --parents` to mean return only the parents, which is not what it does. The `--parent` flag just tells `git log` to *include* the parent's hash in the commit history output (the parent commit's hash appears next to the commit's own hash).

So, if I make another commit and run `git log --parents` again, the output looks like this:

```
commit ntsvthqp2fnoqg5bkv8negqzhea1xebjnwkr6nnm 
6wny3w6k677lr4t4adauv4uctyl6ue38lcozsxbx    <--- second commit's parent
Author: Test <test@gmail.com>                    is the initial commit
Date:   Fri May 02:29:13 2023 +0100

    Second commit

commit 6wny3w6k677lr4t4adauv4uctyl6ue38lcozsxbx
Author: Test <test@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri May 01:29:13 2023 +0100

    Initial commit
```

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of what `--parents` does. But I am not surprised after I read [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---parents). It is totally sub-standard, imprecise, and misleading.

Comment: @j6t, oops, I just realised that after adding a second commit and running `git log --parents` again. The parent's hash appears next to the commit's hash. Since the initial commit has no parents, there is no parent hash!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--parents` instructs to print the parents of the commit if the commit has one or more parents.

```
commit $ownsha1 $parent1sha1 $parent2sha1 ...
```

If the commit does not have any parent, then it prints its own commit only.

```
commit $ownsha1
```

You could try to print non-root commits with and without `--parents` to see the differences.

If you want to print the commit that has at least one parent, use `--min-parents=1` to exclude the root commits.